# Apache Karaf/Fuse integration with Keycloak

Tags: osgi, keycloak, apache-karaf, jaas, jbossfuse

I struggle with Keycloak integration on Karaf (4.2.8) and Fuse (7.5.0). I tried integration separately on both of them and no success.

In first case, I install Fuse (7.5.0) and next I add keycloak osgi features:

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.keycloak/keycloak-osgi-features/8.0.1/xml/features
feature:install keycloak-jaas
```

Next, I add **keycloak-direct-access.json** file to etc with appropriate content. To check the keycloak integration for ssh, I change the **org.apache.karaf.shell** and set realm to keycloak. But afterwards, I am not able to connect via client.bat using keycloak credentials. it asks for the password (even if I provide the password in the command) and after 2-3 attempts it gives the following error:

> No more authentication methods available

Besides of that, when I try to use jaas:realm-manage command to get keycloak user list, if does not work and gives the following error:

> Can't get the list of users (no backing engine service found)

In the second case, I install Apache Karaf (4.2.8) and the almost the same steps as above. But there it also fails.

Additionally, I check the following documentation https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/blob/7.x.redhat-7-x/security/keycloak/fuse-keycloak.adoc . Considering that documentation I do all steps right, but for some reason it fails.

For fuse installation, I checked the logs when I tried to connect via client, and I saw the following warning there

> 2020-02-13 10:06:45,808 | WARN  | 56c97]-nio2-thread-1 | o.a.s.s.s.ServerSessionImpl      | 185 - org.apache.sshd.core - 1.7.0 | exceptionCaught(ServerSessionImpl[null@/127.0.0.1:65456])[state=Opened] IOException: The specified network name is no longer available.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance,

BR,
Farid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Fuse 7, the official quickstarts showing how to integrate Pax Web (the web layer in Fuse Karaf, based on pax-http-undertow) with Keycloak (and RH-SSO) are available in [this Github repository](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/tree/7.x.redhat-7-x/security/keycloak).

The quickstarts cover scenarios related to OSGi HTTP Service, Whiteboard Service, Camel and CXF.

[Additional documentation](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/blob/7.x.redhat-7-x/security/keycloak/fuse-keycloak.adoc) shows how to configure Keycloak instance and Fuse-Karaf itself, so SSH, JMX and Hawtio connections work with Keycloak.

Comment: I put wrong URL in my question, but updated it now. 
I have already done the steps as in https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/blob/7.x.redhat-7-x/security/keycloak/fuse-keycloak.adoc 
Currently, I just want to use SSH over keycloak, at least to see that keycloak integration via keycloak-jaas works.

I checked on both windows and centos operating systems.

Comment: I have fixed my issue. the problem was related to networking. as I use docker containers, so, the instances were not able to see each other properly.